# PowerShell open file in SSMS and do additional customization

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, cmd, powershell-3.0

I am new to PowerShell and struggling trying to understand how to execute my script silently without SSMS program opening up.

***My script needs to do the following :***

1. open SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO
2. open a new query window
3. press ctrl + shift + M to specify values for template parameters
4. set parameter to domain-name and domain-name to mydomain
5. set another parameter to support-group and support-group to
   mysupportgroup
6. then run the sql script (test.sql)

***what I have tried :***

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\ssms.exe"

invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "USDFKUYGTU56697YU\LOCALDB#8934df843" -inputFile "C:\projects\test.sql" | out-File -filepath "C:\projects\test.txt"

Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\ssms.exe" -ArgumentList  "C:\projects\test.sql"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "C:\projects\test.sql" -ServerInstance "MyComputer\MyInstance"
```

I have looked around on how to run these command silently but haven't been able to find a solid solution. Any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated

Comment: You can execute sql from powershell, why are you using ssms?

Comment: @OwlsSleeping i thought i need to open it to set the template parameters then run the script?

Comment: A script is just a text file. Just open the text file and replace the parameters using standard string replace functions.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I understand i can take the text from the sql file and create and  run a powershell script. What i dont fully understand is how i can specify values for template parameters for SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO before excueting the script if im not actually opening SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO

Comment: 1. Open the `.sql` script file into a powershell string variable 2. In the string, find and replace template parameters `<myparameter>` with actual values 3. Connect to SQL Server and execute the SQL string. You do not need SSMS in any of this.

Comment: If you open your .SQL file in notepad you can find/replace parameters with standard find/replace